# bind() error while rerunning the server : Address already in use

Tags: c, sockets

Server Side :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/ip.h>

int main()
{
    int sd,connection_fd;
    int bind_status;
    int listen_status;
    int client_size;

    struct sockaddr_in server , client;

    int readBytes , writeBytes;
    char data[200];

    sd = socket(AF_UNIX,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    if(sd<0){
        perror("Error while creating socket for server side");
    }

    printf("Server socket successfully created\n");

    server.sin_family = AF_UNIX;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(8083);
    int opt = 1;
    setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt, sizeof(opt));

    bind_status = bind(sd,(void*)&server, sizeof(server));

    if(bind_status<0){
        perror("Error in binding address to socket");
    }
    printf("Successfully binded the IP address with the socket\n");

    listen_status = listen(sd,2);

    if(listen_status<0){
        perror("Error while listening for connections");
    }

    printf("Now listening for connection for sockets\n");

    client_size = (int)sizeof(client);
    connection_fd = accept(sd, (void *)&client , &client_size);
    if(connection_fd<0){
        perror("Error while accepting client connection");
    }
    else{
        readBytes = read(connection_fd , data,100);
        if(readBytes<0){
            perror("Error while reading from client");
        }
        else{
            printf("Data received from client is %s\n",data);
        }
        writeBytes = write(connection_fd , "Hi , I am the server!\n",20);
        
        if(writeBytes<0){
            perror("Error while sending data to client");
        }

        else{
            printf("Data sent to client successfully\n");
        }
    }

    close(connection_fd);
    close(sd);
    return 0;
}
```

Client side:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<netinet/ip.h>

int main()
{
    int sd;
    int status;

    struct sockaddr_in server;
    
    int readBytes , writeBytes;
    char data[200];

    sd = socket(AF_UNIX,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(sd<0)
    {
        perror("Error while creating a socket");
    }

    printf("Client socket successfully created!!\n");

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(8083);
    server.sin_family = AF_UNIX;

    int connection_status = connect(sd,(void*)&server,sizeof(server));
    printf("%d\n",connection_status);

    if(connection_status <0){
        perror("Error while connecting with server");
    }
    printf("Client successfully connected to server\n");

    writeBytes = write(sd , "Hi, I am a client", 17);
    if(writeBytes< 0){
        perror("Error while writing to the server");
    }
    else{
        printf("Data sent to the server!\n");
    }

    readBytes = read(sd , data,100);
    if(readBytes<0){
        perror("Error while reading data from server");
    }
    else{
        printf("The data from server is %s \n",data);
    }

    close(sd);
    return 0;
}
```

Once the server and client is run with a new port assigned it works accordingly . But when the server is run again it give address already in use. Cant figure out where is the leak.

Based on some suggestions the server code also has

```
int opt = 1;
    setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt, sizeof(opt));
```

to make it reuse the socket address . But no solution .

Comment: Very likely, the socket is not closed yet when you try to re-run the program.  By default, the actual closure is done in the background after the program closes the socket's file descriptor, and there is an intentional delay.  You can exert some control over that via the `SO_LINGER` option.  Read [the docs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) for more details.

Comment: Note in particular that `SO_REUSEADDR` does not apply to active listening sockets.

Comment: So is there any way that the listening sockets can be closed and do not go to TIME_WAIT.

Comment: You can set the linger time, in seconds, using the `SO_LINGER` option.  I'm not sure whether it works to set that to zero, but you could try.  You should definitely be able to set it to 1. And when you enable linger, the socket `close()` will not return until the socket is actually closed, so you should not see bind failures on subsequent runs (unless they overlap).  The needed wait will be performed automatically by the program.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Not working still .

Comment: Wait.  You are creating *UNIX-domain* sockets (`AF_UNIX`) but binding them to IPv4 addresses (`struct sockaddr_in`).  Your client is also trying to connect to an address that does not actually specify a valid IP address for the host (`INADDR_ANY`).  It's a wonder that any of this is working at all.  Choose one socket flavor and use the appropriate address semantics for that flavor.

Comment: @JohnBollinger found the mistake , thank you.